# Using Google Backup & Sync inside a vm on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I was previously using the "Google Photos Backup" tool inside a Windows 7 VirtualBox VM on Ubuntu. This accessed files on the host Ubuntu using shared folders and work fine.

However "Google Photos Backup" has now been replaced with "Google Backup & Sync"... Trying the same "trick" results in the error

```
Please select a folder on an NTFS drive that is not mounted over a network
```

So I'm after some trick, either at the Windows 7, VirtualBox or Ubuntu level to fool Google Backup & Sync into thinking the shared folder is a local drive.

I appreciate this may be considered off topic, but does cover some Ubuntu aspects.